# Spark withColumn sequential integer based on date

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've got a data set that has companies with a daily production rate of a product.  I want to add a column to that dataframe which will sequentially number based on that company by date.

Ex.
Acme    Product1    1/1/2000    5
Acme    Product1    1/2/2000    7
Acme    Product2    3/1/2000    9
Acme    Product2    3/2/2000    4
Company2    ProductX    4/1/2015    6
Company2    ProductX    4/2/2015    3

I want to add a new column like:
Acme    Product1    1/1/2000    5    **1**
Acme    Product1    1/2/2000    7    **2**
Acme    Product2    3/1/2000    9    **1**
Acme    Product2    3/2/2000    4    **2**
Company2    ProductX    4/1/2015    6    **1**
Company2    ProductX    4/2/2015    3    **2**
Company2    ProductX    4/2/2015    2    **3**

This is all so that I can compare companies and their products based on the new column.  So all of their day one production for a product regardless of date.

Comment: You should attempt to do it and ask when you are stuck or your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windowing with pyspark.sql function `row_number` (alias `rowNumber` works for `spark <= 1.6.X`).

First let's create the dataframe:

```
myDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([["Acme", "Product1", "1/1/2000", 5],
        ["Acme", "Product1", "1/2/2000", 7],
        ["Acme", "Product2", "3/1/2000", 9],
        ["Acme", "Product2", "3/2/2000", 4],
        ["Company2", "ProductX", "4/1/2015", 6],
        ["Company2", "ProductX", "4/2/2015", 3], 
        ["Company2", "ProductX", "4/2/2015", 2]]), 
    ["company", "product", "date", "nb"])

    +--------+--------+--------+---+
    | company| product|    date| nb|
    +--------+--------+--------+---+
    |    Acme|Product1|1/1/2000|  5|
    |    Acme|Product1|1/2/2000|  7|
    |    Acme|Product2|3/1/2000|  9|
    |    Acme|Product2|3/2/2000|  4|
    |Company2|ProductX|4/1/2015|  6|
    |Company2|ProductX|4/2/2015|  3|
    |Company2|ProductX|4/2/2015|  2|
    +--------+--------+--------+---+
```

Now to use the window function:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

resultDF = myDF.withColumn(
    "rowNum", 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("company", "product")
                           .orderBy("date")))

    +--------+--------+--------+---+------+
    | company| product|    date| nb|rowNum|
    +--------+--------+--------+---+------+
    |Company2|ProductX|4/1/2015|  6|     1|
    |Company2|ProductX|4/2/2015|  3|     2|
    |Company2|ProductX|4/2/2015|  2|     3|
    |    Acme|Product2|3/1/2000|  9|     1|
    |    Acme|Product2|3/2/2000|  4|     2|
    |    Acme|Product1|1/1/2000|  5|     1|
    |    Acme|Product1|1/2/2000|  7|     2|
    +--------+--------+--------+---+------+
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it should not have been down voted

Comment: This worked...Thanks!

I'm just learning, so I wasn't sure where to start and everything I tried just gave errors.

A few notes, at first I got "'F' was not defined", so after research I had to add "from pyspark.sql import functions as F" and "from pyspark.sql.window import Window".  Then I got something about rowNumber module was not found.  So again after research, I had to change to F.row_number().